# Android: How can I save GPS coordinates, and start a new activity when found?

Tags: android, android-activity, gps, store

I am attempting to create a simple application whereby GPS coordinates will be stored, and simply display on the screen of the next activity.

So far, I have managed to get the coordinates to display in a toast, so I know the code is working. I am having a problem with the logic. I am attempting to start a new activity (one which will display the coordinates) when the longitude and latitude is found.

Could anyone offer any suggestions as to how I might do something like this?

```
public class GPSActivity extends Activity{

float longitude     = 0;
float latitude      = 0;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);


/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Display.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();


do{
    extras.putFloat("long", longitude);
    extras.putFloat("lat", latitude);
}while(longitude == 0);


// if longitude is no longer zero - meaning it is found
// add extras and call activity.
if(longitude != 0){
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}} // end activity






/* Class My Location Listener */
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {



@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

longitude = (float) loc.getLatitude();
latitude = (float) loc.getLongitude();

String text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
}

}} // End GPS activity
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you have put that section in onCreate(), but if you move it into onLocationChanged() it should work.

```
public class GPSActivity extends Activity{

    float longitude     = 0;
    float latitude      = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */
        LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();

        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);

    }

    /* Class My Location Listener */
    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {        

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        longitude = (float) loc.getLatitude();
        latitude = (float) loc.getLongitude();

        String text = "My current location is: " + "Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() + "Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(GPSActivity.this, Display.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();        

        extras.putFloat("long", longitude);
        extras.putFloat("lat", latitude);        

        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);       

    }
```

Comment: hi, I have tried this approach but the application crashes when trying to start the activity, with a nullpointerexception being thrown.

Comment: Yes, the example assumes that the activity you want to start is Display.class and perhaps that's not the case, right?

Comment: no the display class will show the coordinates as they have been shown